# using hibernate join.fetch to reduce db calls

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity, i dont want multiple selects being made when user is retrieved. Most cases the address is always needed. I know i can use the fetchmode.join on address. My question is will i need to add fetchmode.join on all oneToOne relations in all objects, for it to work? ie in Address make postoffice also fetchmode.join. I also dont want to have all objects returned..

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
     @Id private UUID userId;
     private String username;
     @OneToMany private List<Permission> roles;
     @OneToOne private Address address;
     @OneToOne private payment payment;
}


@Entity
@Data
public class Address{
     @Id private UUID addressId;
     ....
     ....

     @OneToOne private PostOffice postoffice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy, and I would also recommend you avoid using EAGER fetching in general. It's much better to use LAZY fetching by default and instead use entity graphs or DTOs to control what should be fetched.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getUserId();
    String getUsername();
    AddressDto getAddress();

    @EntityView(Address.class)
    interface AddressDto {
        @IdMapping
        UUID getAddressId();
        String getStreet();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: ooh this look good, il look into this.. thanks